# How do I use the count function here properly?

Tags: arrays, matlab, count

[part 4 is what I need help with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbn84.png)

How do I write a set of double for loops to find and count how many times the number (n) occurs in the
array you created in item 3 above.  The answer can be 0.  The size of the array varies so the number of random
numbers varies.   i.e.  a 3x3 array has 9 values where a 6x6 array has 36 values which will increase the chance of
some occurrences of the number.

```
T= 1;
```

while (T==1)

```
r = input('Enter number of rows ') ;
c= input(' Enter number of columns ');
n = input('Enter range of random 0-9 ');
disp(n);

a = uint16(rand(r,c)*n+1);    
fprintf(' n = %5d  \n', n);    
disp('Cool Matrix A');
disp(a);

b = uint16(rand(r,c)*n);      
disp('Cooler Matrix B ' );
disp(b);
```

T= input('Enter 1 to continue \n');
end

Comment: Please [don't post your code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Consider paste your actual code as text and put them in a code block. Also, please post your problem description as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a as your target matrix and n as your target integer to find. finding number of occurence using 2 loop can be done as below.

```
count=0;
size_a=size(a);
for i=1:size_a(1)
    for j=1:size_a(2)
        if a(i,j)==n
            count=count+1;
        end
    end
end
```

But this job can be done much more simply without using for loops by substituting them with matlab's internal function find. This will save time and computation complexity

```
count = length(find(a==n));
```